# I’m clean when I’m on the road

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix is not single
>   My infix is cold to hold
>   My postfix can mean my whole
>   I’m clean when I’m on the road

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is

> BICYCLE

*My prefix is not single*

> The prefix bi- means "two", so not single.

*My infix is cold to hold*

> Icy means extremely cold.

*My postfix can mean my whole*

> Cycle is a synonym for bicycle.

*I’m clean when I’m on the road*

> The bicycle is a clean way of transportation.